# Feature templates do not change when using LYR file and PostgreSQL?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, editing, layer-file, template

We just started migrating from SQL Server to a PostgreSQL Server for production.  Traditionally, we load a LYR file containing all of our symbology, then point it to our new GDB on the SQL Server.  If we needed to modify an existing feature template, we could do so without any trouble.

Now, with PostgreSQL up and running, things are working a little different.  Following the same process, we load in the LYR file, point to our GDB, and start editing.  Now when we try to modify a feature template, specifically a field with a domain, the changes are not applied to features created from the template.  We can open the template, and our changes are visible, but new features created with the template do not reflect changes.

Also, if we set up a new map document, add data with the same symbology as the LYR file (manually, not using the LYR file), there are no troubles with the feature templates.

Are there any known issues/solutions related to my situation?

**EDIT: Software versions**

ArcGIS 10.4.1

PostgreSQL 9.4.21

SQL Server 2014

**EDIT 2: Further testing**

I've updated the PG cluster to 9.4.21, but the problem persists.  I've also tested using LYR files for other schemas we use, and there are no issues there.  I tried opening the LYR file in a fresh MXD, connecting to GDB, saving the MXD, and then running MXD Doctor to see if something was corrupted in the Featur Layer.  No luck there either.

**EDIT 3: ESRI Support**

ESRI Support has been chewing on the issue for 2 months now with no resolution.  They have been able to replicate the issue with ArcMap 10.4 - 10.6, and PostgreSQL 9.4.5 - 10.3.  They are convinced that this is a bug.  I'm surprised no one else has run into this issue before now.  After digging further into our production workflows, I've been able to reproduce the issue with different gdb scehams using MXDs and LYRs.

Comment: Exact software releases are called for on a question like this. If you have a reproducible case, you should take it to Tech Support.

Comment: @Vince Added software versions.  Anything else?

Comment: Both 10.4.1 and 9.4.5 are long in the tooth for any sort of Tech Support call. In fact, I would urgently recommend installing the best 9.4 immediately (9.4.20), and make plans to upgrade to 9.6 (or 10) and 10.6.1 soon.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.  I must've misunderstood the ESRI documentation.  I can (and by the sounds of it should) use the most recent minor version?  What about major major version?  As for 10.6, that's not my call.

Comment: Assuming you're *not* using RDS, 10.6 is a prerequisite for PG 9.6, and 10.6.1 for  PG10.x. Read the support policy doc for details, but yes minor releases are supported except when explicitly *not* supported.